# mod_rewrite according to language with user choice

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have *example.com* which currently redirects to *fr.example.com*, *it.example.com* and *en.example.com* by default.

I want to change to `example.com` which redirects automatically to *example.com/fr/*, *example.com/it/* and *example/en/* by default.

But I want also users who want to see another language to be able to do so `&` not redirect them.

So, if an italian user wants to see the english version of the site, I don't want to force her to see the Italian one.

How can I redirect users to the version which matches their HTTP:Accept-Language to the correct path but if they actually click on a link like `http://example.com/en/foo.html` will not redirect them to `http://example.com/it/foo.html` if they are on an italian computer ?

Current set up is here :

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^fr [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://fr.example.com$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^it [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://it.example.com$1 [L,R=301]

    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://en.example.com$1 [L,R=301]
```

Thank you.

Comment: In another words, you want to redirect only the homepage, not internal links ?

Comment: Not really. If a users clicks on example.com/foo.html, I want to redirect to example.com/[lang]/foo.html. But if a user clicks on example.com/it/foo.html, I want to let her see the italian version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to perform your redirect on root level only.

Replace your current code by this one in your htaccess (which has to be in root folder)

```
RewriteEngine On

# redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect language subdomain to subfolder
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z]{2})\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# redirect root folder to subfolder language user equivalent
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Language} ^(fr|it|en) [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/%1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: So, with this solution, I've got to create a htdocs/en/ htdocs/fr/ & htdocs/it/ subfolders and populate them with their own .htaccess, right ?

Comment: It depends on what you need to do. That's totally up to you. My code redirects subdomaine language to subdirectory language, which supposes those subdirectories exist (or at least you have some rules to handle those virtual subdirectories)

Comment: I'd like not to have to create subfolders which would mean duplicating the code. Ideally changing your second RewriteRule with something like ^([a-z]{2})/faq$ faq.php?lang=$1 [L], ^([a-z]{2})/terms$ terms.php?lang=$1 [L], etc. should do the trick.